# Coding a Slack block message

Tags: python, slack

This works:

```
    client.chat_postMessage(
           channel=channel,
            thread_ts = thread_ts, 
            blocks= 
            [
            {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
               "text": "Danny Torrence left the following review for your property:"
            }
            },
          [ ... and so on... more sections ...]

)
```

But this does not work:

```
client.chat_postMessage(
           channel=channel,
            thread_ts = thread_ts, 
            blocks=blockmsg
        )
```

Where blockmsg is a multiline literal I defined earlier in the program.  Slack just does not publish 'blockmsg' and it is silent, i.e. no error message.

Is there some "gotcha" here?

Comment: Could you refactor your code to convert your multi-line literal into JSON? Slack docs mention that `blocks` is "a JSON-based array of structured blocks, presented as a URL-encoded string."

Comment: Is your literal a string of the JSON or a Python dictionary?

Comment: It was a string of the JSON.  I figured it out,  I had made a typo.  Even one typo is a killer